# Cant fetch duplicate rows PHP

Tags: php, mysql

My code is running for first time perfectly (if & else condition), next time if i execute this code, it is not executing if conditon.Dont know why. Can someone have a look at this. Its is checking the hash value in DB if found do nothing else insert row, but it is duplicating rows.

```
$data = array();
foreach($objJson["statuses"] as $status) {
  $data[] = array("created_at" => $status["created_at"],"text" => $status["text"],"user_img" => $status["user"]["profile_image_url"],"from_user" => $status["user"]["screen_name"],"id" => $status["id"],"media_url" => $status["entities"]["media"][0]["media_url_https"],"hash" => md5($status["created_at"].$status["text"].$status["user"]["screen_name"]));

  $check2 = "SELECT hash FROM tweets where hash=".md5($status["created_at"].$status["text"].$status["user"]["screen_name"])." ";
  $res=mysqli_query($con,$check2);

  if (mysqli_num_rows($res)==1) {

  }
  else
  {
    $check = "INSERT INTO tweets (`created_at`,`text`,`user_img`,`from_user`,`media_url`,`hash`) 
VALUES('".$status["created_at"]."','".$status["text"]."','".$status["user"]["profile_image_url"]."','".$status["user"]["screen_name"]."','".$status["entities"]["media"][0]["media_url_https"]."','".md5($status["created_at"].$status["text"].$status["user"]["screen_name"])."')";
mysqli_query($con,$check);
  }
}
```

Comment: It will execute either the IF or the ELSE block. Or are you saying is executing neither?

Comment: its is executing else conditons, but duplicating rows, I want to stop duplication

Comment: Doesn't "created_at" change with every script run?

Comment: no, its twitter data, so i am matching md5 hash from table and query

Comment: Have you tried printing the value being hashed and checking if it's the same or not?

Comment: Yes, You are right, can you tell me how I get hash value from Data[] and put in insert query

Comment: Attempt to improve indentation

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put user data directly into a query.

Comment: Instead of requesting each of the hashes and then throwing them away you could do a `COUNT()` in your query instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code. I improved the formatting and saw that quotes were missing around the hash, a minor problem:

```
foreach($objJson["statuses"] as $status) {
  $hash   = md5($status["created_at"].$status["text"].$status["user"]["screen_name"]));
  $check  = "SELECT hash FROM tweets WHERE hash = '$hash'";
  $result = mysqli_query($con,$check);
  if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0) {
    $insert = "INSERT INTO tweets (created_at,text,user_img,from_user,media_url,hash) 
               VALUES('".$status["created_at"]."','".
                         $status["text"]."','".
                         $status["user"]["profile_image_url"]."','".
                         $status["user"]["screen_name"]."','".
                         $status["entities"]["media"][0]["media_url_https"]."','".
                         $hash."')";
    mysqli_query($con,$insert);
  }
}
```

I also improved the structure of your code a bit.

Comment: Just a tip, and I don't know if it is useful: Never use code like this outside a function or method. Always try to isolate your variables from the global scope.

Comment: Thanks for tip :) , a minor issue wasted my 1 hour

Comment: I know, a common problem in programming. What can help: better formatting, splitting up your code in smaller parts, and watching the values of variables.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your check lines to:

```
$key = md5($status["created_at"].$status["text"].$status["user"]["screen_name"]);
$check2 = "SELECT hash FROM tweets where hash='".$key."'";
```